# ActionLink helper problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to get through Rob Conery tutorial MVC StoreFront ans I have a problem with a line of code which is a link to a controller action.

```
<div class="categoryNavigation">
    <% foreach (Category parent in ViewData.Model)
       { %>
       <h3><%=parent.Name%></h3>
       <ul>
            <%foreach (Category child in parent.SubCategories)
              { %>
            <li>
                <%=Html.ActionLink<CatalogController>(x=>x.Index(parent.Name,child.Name),child.Name) %>
            </li>
               <% } %>
       </ul>
        <% } %>

</div>
```

I get a message like that : The non generic method 'System.Web.MVC.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,string,string,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions)'  cannot be used with type arguments

Could you help me on that problem

Thanks

I think I have found something  :

On his tutorial for the Html.Action helper code, I can see on intellisense the he's got two choices for this method :

Html.ActionLink
Html.ActionLink<>

I don't have the Html.ActionLink<> choice on mine...

on my Web config file for the pages configuration I have the following :

```
<pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
            <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
            <add namespace="CoderForTraders.Data"/>
            <add namespace="CoderForTraders.Web.Controllers"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Comment: Are you sure that that compilation error is coming from that line in that file? It seems unlikely since you're calling an HTML helper but the error is about an AJAX helper. Are you calling any other helpers in your page?

Comment: No that's all there is in my page. I don't know why I get this ajax reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed the Microsoft.Web.Mvc reference